# How to end a cycle with DIV ?

Tags: php, cycle

```
<div class="product-fields">

<?php
$custom_title = null;
foreach ($this->product->customfieldsSorted['normal'] as $field) { // I set the position to normal

if ( $field->is_hidden )
continue;
if ($field->display) {
?>

<?php if ($field->custom_title != $custom_title) { ?>

 <div class="product-field product-field-type-<?php echo $field->custom_title ?><?php //echo $field->field_type ?>">

<div class="product-fields-title"><?php echo JText::_($field->custom_title); ?></div>

<?php
if ($field->custom_tip)
 echo JHTML::tooltip($field->custom_tip, JText::_($field->custom_title), 'tooltip.png');
}
?>
<span class="product-field-display"><?php echo $field->display ?></span>
<!--<span class="product-field-desc"><?php echo $field->custom_field_desc ?></span>-->

  <?php $custom_title = $field->custom_title; }

}
echo "<br /><br />&raquo;171717&raquo;</div>";

?>
```

I would like to have a closer DIV at the and of cycle of

```
<span class="product-field-display"><?php echo $field->display ?></span>
```

but I dont know where put

```
echo "<br /><br />&raquo;171717&raquo;</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper close of Div tags:

```
<?php
$custom_title = null;
foreach ($this->product->customfieldsSorted['normal'] as $field) { // I set the position to normal

if ( $field->is_hidden )
continue;
if ($field->display) {
?>

<?php if ($field->custom_title != $custom_title) { ?>

 <div class="product-field product-field-type-<?php echo $field->custom_title; //echo $field->field_type ?>">

<div class="product-fields-title"><?php echo JText::_($field->custom_title); ?></div>

<?php
if ($field->custom_tip)
 echo JHTML::tooltip($field->custom_tip, JText::_($field->custom_title), 'tooltip.png');
}
?>
<span class="product-field-display"><?php echo $field->display ?></span>
<!--<span class="product-field-desc"><?php echo $field->custom_field_desc ?></span>-->

  <?php $custom_title = $field->custom_title; }
?>
</div>
<?php
}
echo "<br /><br />&raquo;171717&raquo;";
?>
</div>
```

Comment: I will obtain a </div> at the end of a single 
 <div class="product-field product-field-type-<?php echo $field->custom_title; //echo $field->field_type ?>">


instead I obtain a </div> at the end of single
<span class="product-field-display"><?php echo $field->display ?></span>